# Session expiring for twitter oAuth

Tags: session, twitter, oauth

I am using Abraham Williams' oAuth library to update a status. The application does not have a UI (other than the prompt from Twitter for credentials. Instead, the user enters a URL in the browser.

When the URL is called, I get an error: "Could not post Tweet. Error: Reason: 1".

I inserted some test code, and it seems as if the session is getting lost in between transitions: $_SESSION['tweetmsg'] is set on initial call in index.php, but then when the switch to connect.php happens, it seems as if the session is lost. Any ideas?

Following is the source code:

index.php

```
<?php
include_once '../../winsinclude/tw_config.php';
require_once "../../winsinclude/twitteroauth.php";
require_once "../../winsinclude/OAuth.php";
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
  $_SESSION['tweetmsg'] = create_tweet_text();
  print "<script>self.location='./connect.php');</script>";
}

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(
  CONSUMER_KEY,
  CONSUMER_SECRET,
  $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token'],
  $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret']
);

if (!isset($_SESSION['tweetmsg'])) {
  exit('No tweet value in session or from form');
}
$tweetmsg = $_SESSION['tweetmsg'];
$result = $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $tweetmsg));
unset($_SESSION['tweetmsg']);
if (200 === $connection->http_code) {
  echo 'Tweet Posted: '.$tweetmsg;
}
else {
  echo 'Could not post Tweet. Error: '.$httpCode.' Reason: '.
  session_destroy();
}
function create_tweet_text () {
  return 'this is a test';
}
```

connect.php

```
?php
session_start();
include_once '../../winsinclude/tw_config.php';
require_once "../../winsinclude/twitteroauth.php";
require_once "../../winsinclude/OAuth.php";

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK.'callback.php');

$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

$url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($request_token);
print "<script>self.location='$url';</script>";
```

callback.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once '../../winsinclude/tw_config.php';
require_once "../../winsinclude/twitteroauth.php";
require_once "../../winsinclude/OAuth.php";

if (
  isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) 
  && $_SESSION['oauth_token'] !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token']
) {
  echo 'Session expired';
}
else {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth(
    CONSUMER_KEY,
    CONSUMER_SECRET,
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'],
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']
  );
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);
  print "<script>self.location='index.php';</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently Twitter deactivated a number of http urls for oAuth and replaced them with https equivalents. If you can see the URL string http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token in the includes then it means you need to follow https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10803 and change all the calls to https...

Comment: If you read the source code I posted, you will see that I am not calling the twitter API without specific end points, and that I am using Abraham Williams' library, which does not call the API libs without the use of a specific end point.